# Calendários brasileiros utilizando Pandas- python

Tags: datetime, pandas, calendar

Como eu faço para importar o calendário de feriados do Brasil utilizando a biblioteca pandas em python. Por exemplo, se eu utilizar o seguinte código:

```
from pandas.tseries.holiday import *

feriados= USFederalHolydayCalendar()

for feriado in feriados.holidays(start="2020-01-01", end="2020-12-31"):
    print(feriado)
```

Eu consigo todos os feriados do Estados Unidos. Como eu faço para conseguir a mesma coisa, porém com o calendário brasileiro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primeiramente, é bom verificar se existe um método especificamente para o Brasil nesse módulo. Para verificar os métodos deste e de qualquer outro módulo, utilize a função *builtin* `dir()`. Assim, temos:

```py
from pandas.tseries import holiday
    
print(dir(holiday))
```

que retorna:

```
['AbstractHolidayCalendar', 'DateOffset', 'Day', 'Easter', 'EasterMonday', 'FR', 'GoodFriday', 'Holiday', 'HolidayCalendarFactory', 'HolidayCalendarMetaClass', 'List', 'MO', 'PerformanceWarning', 'SA', 'SU', 'Series', 'TH', 'TU', 'Timestamp', 'USColumbusDay', 'USFederalHolidayCalendar', 'USLaborDay', 'USMartinLutherKingJr', 'USMemorialDay', 'USPresidentsDay', 'USThanksgivingDay', 'WE', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'after_nearest_workday', 'before_nearest_workday', 'date_range', 'datetime', 'get_calendar', 'holiday_calendars', 'nearest_workday', 'next_monday', 'next_monday_or_tuesday', 'next_workday', 'np', 'previous_friday', 'previous_workday', 'register', 'sunday_to_monday', 'timedelta', 'warnings', 'weekend_to_monday']
```

ou seja, realmente parece ter dados nesse módulo apenas para os EUA. A segunda opção é verificar se existe um outro módulo que faça a mesma coisa com dados de outros países. De fato, existe um módulo apenas para isso que pode ser encontrado nesse [link](https://pypi.org/project/holidays/). Fazendo o mesmo teste para esse novo pacote, temos:

```py
import holidays

print(dir(holidays))
```

que retorna:

```
['APR', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'AUG', 'AW', 'Argentina', 'Aruba', 'Australia', 'Austria', 'BE', 'BG', 'BR', 'BY', 'Belarus', 'Belgium', 'Brazil', 'Bulgaria', 'CA', 'CH', 'CL', 'CO', 'CZ', 'Canada', 'Chile', 'Colombia', 'CountryHoliday', 'Croatia', 'Czech', 'Czechia', 'DE', 'DEC', 'DK', 'DO', 'Denmark', 'DominicanRepublic', 'ECB', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'Egypt', 'England', 'Estonia', 'EuropeanCentralBank', 'FEB', 'FI', 'FRA', 'FRI', 'Finland', 'France', 'GB', 'GR', 'Germany', 'Greece', 'HK', 'HND', 'HR', 'HU', 'HolidayBase', 'Honduras', 'HongKong', 'Hungary', 'IE', 'IL', 'IND', 'IS', 'ISR', 'IT', 'Iceland', 'India', 'Ireland', 'IsleOfMan', 'Israel', 'Italy', 'JAN', 'JP', 'JUL', 'JUN', 'Japan', 'KE', 'Kenya', 'LT', 'LU', 'Lithuania', 'Luxembourg', 'MAR', 'MAY', 'MON', 'MX', 'Mexico', 'NG', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NOV', 'NZ', 'Netherlands', 'NewZealand', 'Nicaragua', 'Nigeria', 'NorthernIreland', 'Norway', 'OCT', 'PE', 'PL', 'PT', 'PTE', 'PY', 'Paraguay', 'Peru', 'Poland', 'Polish', 'Portugal', 'PortugalExt', 'RS', 'RU', 'Russia', 'SAT', 'SE', 'SEP', 'SG', 'SI', 'SK', 'SUN', 'Scotland', 'Serbia', 'Singapore', 'Slovak', 'Slovakia', 'Slovenia', 'SouthAfrica', 'Spain', 'Sweden', 'Switzerland', 'TAR', 'THU', 'TUE', 'UA', 'UK', 'US', 'Ukraine', 'UnitedKingdom', 'UnitedStates', 'WED', 'WEEKEND', 'Wales', 'ZA', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', 'argentina', 'aruba', 'australia', 'austria', 'belarus', 'belgium', 'brazil', 'bulgaria', 'canada', 'chile', 'colombia', 'constants', 'countries', 'createHolidaySum', 'croatia', 'czechia', 'denmark', 'dominican_republic', 'egypt', 'estonia', 'european_central_bank', 'finland', 'france', 'germany', 'greece', 'holiday_base', 'honduras', 'hongkong', 'hungary', 'iceland', 'india', 'ireland', 'israel', 'italy', 'japan', 'kenya', 'list_supported_countries', 'lithuania', 'luxembourg', 'mexico', 'netherlands', 'new_zealand', 'nicaragua', 'nigeria', 'norway', 'paraguay', 'peru', 'poland', 'portugal', 'russia', 'serbia', 'singapore', 'slovakia', 'slovenia', 'south_africa', 'spain', 'sweden', 'switzerland', 'ukraine', 'united_kingdom', 'united_states', 'utils']
```

Agora basta reescrever o código com o novo módulo:

```py
import holidays
    
feriados= holidays.Brazil()
    
for feriado in feriados['2020-01-01': '2020-12-31'] :
    print(feriado)
```

que retorna:

```
2020-01-01
2020-02-25
2020-02-26
2020-04-10
2020-04-12
2020-04-21
2020-05-01
2020-06-11
2020-09-07
2020-10-12
2020-11-02
2020-11-15
2020-12-25
```

Comment: Esqueceu de adicionar o Link.

Comment: Verdade @NetoCosta vou adicionar agora. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Existem várias formas:

1. Usar o pacote [holidays](https://pypi.org/project/holidays/);
2. Usar o pacote [workalendar](https://pypi.org/project/workalendar/);
3. Usar o pacote [pandas_market_calendars](https://pandas-market-calendars.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pandas_market_calendars.html#pandas_market_calendars.exchange_calendar_bmf.BMFExchangeCalendar) (para a BM&F BOVESPA);
4. Cadastrar seus próprios feriados no Pandas.

Como você pediu especificamente pela Pandas, segue um exemplo de código:

**In:**

```
from datetime import datetime, date
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.holiday import AbstractHolidayCalendar, GoodFriday, Holiday, Easter, Day

class Feriados_SP(AbstractHolidayCalendar):
    rules = [
        Holiday('Confraternização Universal', month=1, day=1),
        Holiday('Aniversário de São Paulo', month=1, day=25),
        Holiday('Segunda-Feira de Carnaval', month=1, day=1, offset=[Easter(), Day(-48)]),
        Holiday('Terça-Feira de Carnaval', month=1, day=1, offset=[Easter(), Day(-47)]),
        Holiday('Quarta-Feira de Cinzas', month=1, day=1, offset=[Easter(), Day(-46)]),
        # Sexta-feira Santa
        GoodFriday,
        Holiday('Corpus Christi', month=1, day=1, offset=[Easter(), Day(60)]),
        Holiday('Tiradentes', month = 4, day = 21),
        Holiday('Dia do Trabalho', month = 5, day = 1),
        Holiday('Revolução Constitucionalista', month=7, day=9, start_date='1997-01-01'),
        Holiday('Independência do Brasil', month = 9, day = 7),
        Holiday('Nossa Senhora Aparecida', month = 10, day = 12),
        Holiday('Finados', month = 11, day = 2),
        Holiday('Proclamação da República', month = 11, day = 15),
        Holiday('Dia da Consciencia Negra', month=11, day=20, start_date='2004-01-01'),
        Holiday('Vespera de Natal', month=12, day=24),
        Holiday('Natal', month = 12, day = 25)]

sp_cal = Feriados_SP()
sp_feriados = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(calendar=sp_cal)
feriados_sp = sp_cal.holidays(datetime(2000, 12, 31), datetime(2079, 12, 31))

start = datetime(2020, 3, 1)
end = datetime(2020, 5, 5)
pd.bdate_range(start, end, freq='C', holidays=feriados_sp)
```

**Out:**

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-03-02', '2020-03-03', '2020-03-04', '2020-03-05',
               '2020-03-06', '2020-03-09', '2020-03-10', '2020-03-11',
               '2020-03-12', '2020-03-13', '2020-03-16', '2020-03-17',
               '2020-03-18', '2020-03-19', '2020-03-20', '2020-03-23',
               '2020-03-24', '2020-03-25', '2020-03-26', '2020-03-27',
               '2020-03-30', '2020-03-31', '2020-04-01', '2020-04-02',
               '2020-04-03', '2020-04-06', '2020-04-07', '2020-04-08',
               '2020-04-09', '2020-04-13', '2020-04-14', '2020-04-15',
               '2020-04-16', '2020-04-17', '2020-04-20', '2020-04-22',
               '2020-04-23', '2020-04-24', '2020-04-27', '2020-04-28',
               '2020-04-29', '2020-04-30', '2020-05-04', '2020-05-05'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='C')
```